# A theoretical/mathematical approach to cost-benefit analysis and cost-utility analysis in health economics

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, mathematical-economics

I am looking to get some resources looking at health economics from a pure mathematical point of view, ie developing models using partial differential equations or complex analysis.

In particular, I am looking for derivations and models relating to cost-benefit analysis, cost-utility analysis, the relationship between CBA/CUA and social welfare and so on.

I am currently going through *Health Economics* by Peter Zweifel, and though it has a serious bit of mathematics, I am looking for something even more theoretical.

In addition, I am looking for research papers published that deal with different types of models relating CBA and CUA - again more mathematical in nature.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly.  Something like this:  https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=225726 (later published in JHE).  Something like this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18619695